# Can this problem be a form of Nonlinear Programming?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

How we can reformulate blew problem as a form of nonlinear programming problems?
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
& \min&\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_n} &\\ 
& \text{s.t.}&x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=n &\\
& & x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=k\quad \text{where}\quad \sqrt{n} < k \leq n &
\end{array}
$$

Comment: so, does it mean, you don't like the $\sqrt n < k$ part? is there a reason for $<$?

Comment: Unfortunately, i dont know. I see this problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083702/minimizing-sum-of-reciprocals)

Comment: there is not any answer?